# Mod rewrite - redirect issue - local server is fine, live server isn't

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Having a bit of a problem with the below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteBase /

#Add trailing slash if not a directory or file, but not if it contains a dot

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

# Don't redirect these directories

RewriteRule ^/?_images/.+$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?_lib/.+$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?_scripts/.+$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?_temp/uploads/.+$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?_template/.+$ - [L]

# Redirect via router, but not these files

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(\/!favicon.ico|robots.txt|sitemap.xml).*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The problem I'm having is the 'not redirecting directories' - basically files in these folders should still show, - this was working correctly, but I'm having a bit of trouble displaying something from the `/_lib/images/` directory - for some reason I always get a 404 error thrown up (possibly because it goes via the router).

On closer examination by displaying the error number, it actually seems to be a 406 error (which I've not come across before) and the 404 probably results from not having a 406 error page.

The weird thing is, it works perfectly locally on XAMPP but not on the live server - also, if I rename `_lib/images/` to, say, `_lib/a/` it will work perfectly ... so the question is, am I completely missing something here? Even a simple 'hello world' results the same....

Comment: Is this in an `.htaccess`,  If so the `^/?...` is a botch.  You won't see the leading `/` -- see apache doc'n.

Comment: Also `RewriteRule .*[^/]$ ...` => no trailing slash so isn;t `%{REQUEST_URI} !/$` a redundant condition?

Comment: Yes, this is `.htaccess` - I'm not sure where I got `^/?...` from but it seemed to work, maybe I can remove the `?` - I'm not too great with `.htaccess` which is probably why there are redundant processes...

Comment: The thing is... I just removed `?` and my scripts no longer called those files, so it must actually be correct...

Comment: I go back to my 1st Q:  is this an `.htaccess` rule set, because to quote the Apache documentation: "In `Directory` and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the _filesystem_ path, _after_ removing the prefix that lead the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "`app1/index.html`" or "`index.html`" depending on where the directives are defined)."

Answer (score 0):

> **406 Not Acceptable** The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.

Sounds like you don't have the associations for your image file types set up on the server.  Move an image to DOCROOT, and then try to display it.  If it returns a 406, then you need to set up the correct file associations.

Comment: I'm not totally sure about the 406 thing - but 406.html appeared when I did `echo $_GET['route'];` on index.php ... but the images/php scripts start working in that folder if i rename it to anything but `images` for some reason, which is why I think it is probably something to do with the rest of the .htaccess file